# Remove one level dept array and associate value to its parent key

Tags: php, arrays

Going crazy about that, please how can I turn this array:

```
Array
(
    [par] => XXX
    [price_item] => 100
    [value] => 130
    [qnt] => Array
        (
            [130] => 99
        )

)
```

into this:

```
Array
(
    [par] => XXX
    [price_item] => 100
    [value] => 130
    [qnt] => 99

)
```

In a foreach loop?

*Notes:*
I can't specify the key **[130]** as it could be a different number, but the array levels structure is always the same as well as the **[qnt]** key, thank you.

Comment: Search for `array_flatten`.  https://codegists.com/snippet/php/array_flattenphp_rollinsb1010_php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to overwrite your array by getting the first element from the given array:

```
//$yourArray
if(is_array($yourArray['qnt'])){//check if array, better safe
    $values = array_values($yourArray['qnt']); //get values as array
    $yourArray['qnt'] = $values[0];//get first and rewrite yout initial array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're certain that it will always be one element in your array or you just want to pick the first one up then you can use something like following:

```
$data['par'] = 'XXX';
$data['price_item'] = 100;
$data['value'] = 130;
$data['qnt'] = ['130'=>99];

$data['qnt'] = (is_array($data['qnt']) && !empty($data['qnt'])) ? array_pop($data['qnt']) : $data['qnt'];

print_r($data);
```

Which would output into something like:

```
Array ( [par] => XXX [price_item] => 100 [value] => 130 [qnt] => 99 )
```